# dd command on running system makes backup image with older versions of files

Tags: linux, backup, dd

I use these commands in a script to create an image backup of an SD card while a Linux OS is running on it -- OpenWrt.

The rootfs is 1000MiB so I only dd the first 300 blocks. This way I can restore the boot and root filesystems in the backup to any other sd card I like using Win32 Disk Imager, (selecting "Read Only Allocated Partitions")

```
imagesPath="/mnt/usb/openwrt/BackupOfImages/"
image_file=${imagesPath}OpenWrt-Image-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").img.gz

sync
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M count=300 | pv | gzip > $image_file
```

However, when I gunzip and mount the created .img file I see that certain files I was working on... the latest versions of them were not backed up but instead the backup contains older versions of those files. Recent edits I made before running the backup script are not included in the backup. I thought that using the sync command before the dd command in my script would flush caches so the latest versions of all files would be backed up?

I know that best practice is to unmount the filesystems on the sd card before running the dd command but my use case will not allow me to do that. What else am I doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: `/dev/mmcblk0`is either a raw device address or a partition, which may well contain a file system. However, accessing the device in this way avoids any of the subtleties of the file system. I believe you are copying contiguous sectors which may represent free blocks, directories with entries marked as not-in-use, and all kinds of other junk.

Comment: i don't get why you create incomplete backup. how can you know what is in first 300 blocks? i would at least dd desired partitions instead of whole emmc. also the dump most likely do not contain rootfs (at least, not straightforward, that's from zimage compressed ramdisk). no matter what you change in rootfs the changes won't survive reboot (on embedded system)

Comment: I have tested it and I can restore the backup using Win32DiskImager so it does work. I make this "incomplete" backup so the backup file can be kept small. The system is OpenWrt which I am running on a Pi4. The boot and root fs are contained within the first few 100MBs of the sd card. It seems like edits I am making to files are not going to the sd card but being held in cache or something. Would you know is there a way to flush that cache to the filesystem storage on the sd card? So I can run the dd command and get an image of the latest data.

Comment: "_I use these commands in a script to create an image backup of an SD card while a Linux OS is running on it_". If you're lucky the backup will be obviously corrupt. If you're unlucky the backup will appear to be valid. You cannot safely backup a filesystem image that's being used unless you have the ability to backup a snapshot (LVM, btrfs, etc.)

Comment: "_I know that best practice is to unmount the filesystems on the sd card before running the dd command but my use case will not allow me to do that. What else am I doing wrong?_". Nothing. It simply demonstrates that you cannot reliably and safely backup a live system like this.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the sync command is not at the right place.
I'm not a specialist, however I would write it :

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M count=300 && sync | gzip > $image_file
```

Comment: This would write the output of `sync` to your `$image_file`, i.e. nothing. A raw dump of the source SD card would be written to _stdout_, i.e. your terminal